# Passing stateParams in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm moving to stateless components in my angular 1.x app.

I moved out all data loading from the controller code, and I'm using the `ui-router`'s `resolve` functionality. As I handle every internal state change with a `$state` transition in the same `$state`, I don't want to fetch all that data from the backend, only when it's required (I need different data).

In order to acquire this behavior, I'm relying heavily on params. Example:

```
...
.state('myapp.child', {
  url: '/child',
  controller: function ($state, foo, bar) {
    function someEvent() {
      // Provision $stateParams to prevent fetching
      $state.go($state.current, {foo: foo, bar:bar});
    }
  },
  params: {
    foo: null,
    bar: null
  },
  resolve: {
    /**
    * @ngInject
    */
    foo: function(fooService, $stateParams) {
      if ($stateParams.foo !== null) {    // <= Duplication
        return foo;
      } else {
        return fooService.get();
      }
    },
    /**
    * @ngInject
    */
    bar: function(barService, $stateParams) {
      if ($stateParams.bar !== null) {    // <= Duplication
        return bar;
      } else {
        return barService.get();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My question is: Is there any way to directly tell the router to resolve those values? Or is there a nice way to avoid that null checks in the resolve block?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternaries and ES6 (although the ES6 is just the lambda) to clean it up a little. I added a lodash function in, but you can simply use the === check as you had:

```
bar: function(barService, $stateParams) =>
  return !_.isNull($stateParams.bar) ? $stateParams.bar : barService.get()
```

Comment: I use this in some places, but the lines tend to get too long. What I'm looking for is a way to auto-resolve `bar`. Or pass that object in `$state.go` as a resolution instead as $stateParams.

Comment: If you're looking to resolve first, then pass it as a $stateParams in the $state.go you're missing the point of ui-router. The resolves are there to do just that. The lines getting 'too long' seems more of an aesthetic aspect rather than a functional programming aspect.